# How to observe paste event by shortcut (Command + V ) in mac app

Tags: macos, event-handling, copy-paste, keyboard-events, nspasteboard

In my mac app, I need observe the shortcut of paste from pasteboard, then will log something.

Is this possible and how to do it ?

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: Definitely this has to be in the responder chain (with menuitem validation) because you have a mainmenu with menuitem called paste (CMD+V). So when you implement paste method for the first responder (nsview...) you can catch that event.

Comment: Thanks Marek. Do you have any code for clues ? quite new to this area and that code may accelerate it.

Comment: as simple as this -(void)paste:(id)sender -> that's the only code your first responder has to implement.

Comment: @Forrest did you find any solution for your problem. If you have code please paste it here. I am also  facing same issue.